# Dart unit test giving inconsistent results

Tags: unit-testing, dart

I have a fairly simply unit test which has been working without issue for a long time.

It has suddenly started failing.

When I run/debug the unit test in vscode the test succeeds.

When I run the test from the cli it succeeds on windows but not on linux.

dart run test -j1  test/src/functions/ask_test.dart

Which is kind of interesting as there is nothing windows/linux specific.
The test has also been working for a long time on linux.

```dart
  test('ask.any - throws', () {
    final validator = Ask.any([
      Ask.fqdn,
      Ask.ipAddress(),
      Ask.inList(['localhost'])
    ]);

    expect(
        () => validator.validate('abc'),
        throwsA(predicate<AskValidatorException>((e) =>
            e is AskValidatorException && e.message == 'Invalid FQDN.')));
  });
```

The test gives the following error:

```
Error: Expected: throws satisfies function
  Actual: <Closure: () => String>
   Which: threw AskValidatorException:<Invalid FQDN.>
          stack package:dcli/src/functions/ask.dart 760:7  _AskValidatorAny.validate
                test/src/functions/ask_test.dart 65:25     main.<fn>.<fn>
                package:test_api                           expect
                test/src/functions/ask_test.dart 64:5      main.<fn>
```

As you can see validate method is doing exactly what is expected (throwing).
The problem seems to be that the unit test frame work is not seeing it as a match.

This is the validator which is throwing as expected.

```dart
class _AskFQDN extends AskValidator {
  const _AskFQDN();
  @override
  String validate(String line) {
    final finalLine = line.trim().toLowerCase();

    if (!isFQDN(finalLine)) {
      throw AskValidatorException(red('Invalid FQDN.'));
    }
    return finalLine;
  }
}
```

I'm using test 1.17.5 on Dart 2.13.

The code is from the DCli package which you can find here:
https://github.com/bsutton/dcli

The specific unit test is here

https://github.com/bsutton/dcli/blob/master/test/src/functions/ask_test.dart

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this will solve your problem, but you can make your assertion a bit cleaner if you do it like this:

```
expect(
    () => validator.validate('abc'),
    throwsA(isA<AskValidatorException>().having((e) =>
        e.message == 'Invalid FQDN.')));
```